# Webdriver - Get the count of elements from li drop-down?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Saw few questions about this but I think that they are not giving the answer that I'm seeking since all of them were using Select class and I can't use that class since the drop-down is not using select tag.

So I can click and I can display all the options that are available in my drop-down list but I can't display the count for all of them.

I have this code for displaying all the options of my drop-down

```
List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/ul/li[1]/span/ul"));
   for ( WebElement element: allText) { 
       System.out.println(element.getText());
   }
```

but I can't display count for all the options in the list. 
I used this

```
System.out.println(allText.size());
```

on different places in the codebut it always showed 1.
What should I use in order to show the count for all the elements in the drop-down ?

The HTML for the list looks something like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">        
                        <li><a pid="null" ng-click="option = null" href="">Option 0</a></li>                 
                        <li><a pid="1" ng-click="option = 1" href="">Option 1</a></li>               
                        <li><a pid="2" ng-click="option = 2" href="">Option 2</a></li>
                        <li><a pid="3" ng-click="option = 3" href="">Option 3</a></li>
                        <li><a pid="4" ng-click="option = 4" href="">Option 4</a></li>                  
                     </ul>
```

So I need to get the number 5 for the count.

Comment: by.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a") strore in list<webelements> then use for loop it works.....

Comment: Tried this but I still can't get the count for elements in the ddl.
Tried like this ` List<WebElement> allText1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a"));
     for ( WebElement element: allText1) { 
         System.out.println(element.getText());
         System.out.println(allText1.size());
     }`
also tried with putting the size expretion out from the for loop and still getting the same

Comment: you made mistake here  ->"System.out.println(allText1.size()); "   replce this with element.size();

Comment: There is no method size() for type WebElement so this System.out.println(element.size()); won't work

Comment: Yeah tried that in the beggining but getsize() is giving the size in pixels.

Comment: int x=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a")).size();   syso(x);

Comment: If I use only this statment it gives me some ranodm number which is not correct

Comment: Not regarding the question as it seems to be solved, but that xpath looks far too unstable. Might I suggest using a css selector instead? just looking at it I'm fairly confident .dropdown-menu>li>a should be sufficient to locate your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 1 `<UL>` element, multiple `<LI>`. Use xpath to the `<LI>` not the `<UL>`.

You should end up with this.

`List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/ul/li[1]/span/ul/li"));`

Comment: Tried that but still getting count of 1 instead of 5.

Comment: Edited to reflect xpath required based on the xpath listed

Comment: Yeah this worked. It gives the count of element for the selected ddl. 

Note:Only thing that I couldn't do is find the actual xPath using firebug, I could find the same xPath but without the last "/li". I guess that's why this xPath expression can't be used for both giving the count of elements and displaying its text content.